# Laravel pivot table and Model Events

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm working on a game and I am currently doing the admin section to add games and levels.

I have games and levels referenced through a pivot table with an "order" column.

My game model:

```
class Game extends Eloquent {

    public function levels() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Level')->withPivot('order');
    }
}
```

My level model:

```
class Level extends Eloquent {

    public function game() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Game')->withPivot('order');
    }
}
```

What I would like to achieve is to auto populate the order column when a level is added, and create moveup() and movedown() functions.

I have tried setting up a model event on the level model to achieve this but was unsuccessful.

Comment: What do you mean by "auto-increment the order on level creation"? DOes your pivot table have more than two columns?

Comment: Hi, I'm used to symfony's "Sortable" behavior. What I mean is that when I add a new level it populates the order column automatically in relation with the game it is added to and the number of levels which belong to that game already. My pivot table has four columns (ID, game_id, level_id, order).

Comment: I understand... I believe you'll have to take care of that manually, maybe using a filter on your level's `create` action. Hopefully someone comes up with a better solution since this looks like a common issue...

Comment: check this package https://github.com/fico7489/laravel-pivot

Answer (score 4):

First off, that kind of order is rather one-way. You can't use the same column for game's levels order and the other way around.

Now, you can achieve what you need for example by overriding `attach` method on the relation to check current max position and add next for insert accordingly (not create event or whatsoever since this has nothing to do with the `level` creation itself, rather with attaching it to the game).

That being said you would need to extend Eloquent `Model` or use a trait in order to use your custom `BelongsToMany` relation. Something like below should do the job (no comments etc to make it possibly concise).

```
// Game model
class Game extends Eloquent {

  use SortablePivotModelTrait;

  public function levels()
  {
    return $this->sortableBelongsToMany('Level', 'order')->withPivot('order');
  }

  //...
}
```

---

```
// SortablePivotModelTrait.php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

trait SortablePivotModelTrait {

    public function sortableBelongsToMany($related, $orderColumn = null, $table = null, $foreignKey = null, $otherKey = null, $relation = null)
    {
        // all the code of belongsToMany method needs to go here
        // ...

        // then just:
        return new SortableBelongsToMany($query, $this, $table, $foreignKey, $otherKey, $relation, $orderColumn);
    }

}
```

---

```
// SortableBelongsToMany.php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany;

class SortableBelongsToMany extends BelongsToMany {

    protected $orderColumn;

    public function __construct(Builder $query, Model $parent, $table, $foreignKey, $otherKey, $relationName = null, $orderColumn = 'order')
    {
        $this->orderColumn = $orderColumn;

        parent::__construct($query, $parent, $table, $foreignKey, $otherKey, $relationName);
    }

    public function attach($id, array $attributes = array(), $touch = true)
    {
        $attributes = array_merge($attributes, [$this->getOrderColumnName() => $this->getNextPosition()]);

        return parent::attach($id, $attributes, $touch);
    }

    public function getNextPosition()
    {
        return 1 + $this->newPivotQuery()->max($this->getOrderColumnName());
    }

    public function getOrderColumnName()
    {
        return $this->orderColumn;
    }

}
```

---

This way you can do this:

```
$level = new Level;
// do some stuff with the created level

$game = Game::find($id);

// then
$game->save($level);

// or
$level->save();
$game->levels()->attach($level);
```

Comment: a couple of typos there.. but other than that, seems to be working just fine.

Comment: @UnamataSanatarai Thank you for this helpful and insightful comment, I'm really glad you posted it!